# when should python3 object created in venv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-venv, pyvenv

python newbie here.
I am on a windows machine and used Windows Subsystem for Linux(WSL) to execute commands.

I created my **venv**(folder) by entering:

`python3 -m venv venv`

and it would give me a new venv folder as below:
[image]

and then activated the virtual environment using:
`source venv/bin/activate`

however, I am having an issue as I executed another command and it is looking for **python3** which should be present as in this path: venv/bin/python3

[image]

I am curious how should python3 created in venv. Thanks!

Comment: which command is looking for python3 in that location?

Comment: I used this command: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you are confused about the Python virtual environment

first, the virtual environment is designed to establish a command execution environment for each project。

then. the first your code `python3 -m venv venv` call the system python command and the python3 should in `/usr/bin/python3` and  linked with `/usr/bin/python3.x`
but, if you activate the virtual environment of Python, the virtualenv will and the `{you_dir}/venv/bin` to the system path and you will call python through `/venv/bin/python`
to execute you python code.

there is no need create an link of /ven/bin/python3. but if you want, you can do it!

Comment: I see. thanks for the elaboration. It also means that it's not the case for having an issue. I used Debian-based Linux distro instead of Ubuntu. so that fixed the problem and I was able to complete the list of commands and make the api up and running locally.